# linking mongocxx using cmakelists file in Linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, cmake

i am new to cmake and also to mongocxx. I have installed the mongocxx using the instructions given on the site http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/. My installatio is fine. Now I am trying to connect with mongodb using cmake in my project. When i write the following cmakelists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(PROJECT_NAME)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(PROJECT_NAME main.cpp)

find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)
find_package(libbsoncxx REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories("/usr/local/include/mongocxx/v_noabi")
include_directories("/usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi")
include_directories("/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0")
include_directories("/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0")
include_directories("/usr/local/lib")


target_link_libraries(PROJECT_NAME ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(PROJECT_NAME ${LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES})
```

it gives me following error :

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
By not providing "Findlibmongocxx.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"libmongocxx", but CMake did not find one.

 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libmongocxx" with
any of the following names:

libmongocxxConfig.cmake
libmongocxx-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "libmongocxx" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
 "libmongocxx_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
 "libmongocxx" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/home/fedora/testmongo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I also tried to run my cpp file with this method given on above website.

code of my cpp file is

```
  #include <cstdint>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
  #include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
  #include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>
  #include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
  #include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
  #include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/helpers.hpp>
  #include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
  #include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/array.hpp>


   using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_array;
   using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
   using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
   using bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
   using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_array;
   using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document;
   mongocxx::instance instance{}; // This should be done only once.

   int main() {
   std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;


    mongocxx::client conn{ mongocxx::uri{ "mongodb://localhost:27017" } };
    auto coll = conn["test"]["coll"];
    std::vector<bsoncxx::document::value> documents;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
       documents.push_back(bsoncxx::builder::stream::document{} << "i" << i 
     << finalize);
       }
    coll.insert_many(documents);

     return 0;
     }
```

and im trying to compile it with this command. its not giving any error
c++ --std=c++11 .cpp
-I/usr/local/include/mongocxx/v_noabi -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0

-I/usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 
-L/usr/local/lib -lmongocxx -lbsoncxx
It complies without any errors and also generate output file a.out, but i don't know how to run that output file. its not running with

```
  ./a.out
```

gives following error
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries:
libmongocxx.so._noabi: cannot open shared object file: No such file
or directory """" This is the exact error i got
what should i do to correct this error or run the below executable file?

Comment: The fact that your executable (`a.out`) is not run most likely means problem with your source file (`main.cpp`). You need to add code from this file into the question post for we being able to help you.

Comment: Please check it now. i don't know how to run a.out. Should it not run simple by ./a.out?

Comment: Assuming you have `a.out` file in the current directory, `./a.out` should run the program. Probably, the error message is printed by your program. Show (add to the question post) the error message **exactly**. See e.g. [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) on meta why exact error message is important.

Comment: """./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libmongocxx.so._noabi: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory """" This is the exact error i got

Answer (score 0):

```
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/lib64
```

These step resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your CMakeLists.txt. Change $YOUR_PROJECT_NAME with your project's name.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

if(POLICY CMP0025)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0025 NEW)
endif()

project($YOUR_PROJECT_NAME CXX)

if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

if (NOT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Werror")
endif()

find_package(mongocxx REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

# Visual Studio pre 2017 requires boost polyfill.
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC" AND CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD LESS 17)
  find_package(Boost 1.56.0 REQUIRED)
  if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 3.15.0)
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  else()
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Boost::boost)
  endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PRIVATE mongo::mongocxx_shared
)

add_custom_target(run
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}
    DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}
)
    
get_target_property(LIBMONGOCXX_DEFINITIONS mongo::mongocxx_shared INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
list(FIND LIBMONGOCXX_DEFINITIONS "BSONCXX_STATIC" LIST_IDX)
if (${LIST_IDX} GREATER -1)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Expected BSONCXX_STATIC to not be defined")
endif()
list(FIND LIBMONGOCXX_DEFINITIONS "MONGOCXX_STATIC" LIST_IDX)
if (${LIST_IDX} GREATER -1)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Expected MONGOCXX_STATIC to not be defined")
endif()
```